# pygtk scale image to width and height

Tags: python, linux, pygtk, raspbian

is it possible to read an image using Python and pyGTK
and change the displayed size (i.e width=xxx height=xxx pixels)?

Sorry, about this question. It probably is very simple,
but I haven't found an answer yet.

Comment: Is the issue solved? If yes, select the good answer please, to let other users what is the solution. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

```
width = xxx
height = xxx

im = gtk.Image()
pixbuf = gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_file("my.jpg")  # Your image file
scaled_buf = pixbuf.scale_simple(width, height, gtk.gdk.INTERP_BILINEAR)
im.set_from_pixbuf(scaled_buf)
im.show()
```

For more informations about the last argument of `scale_simple`, see [interp_type](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gdkpixbuf.html#method-gdkpixbuf--scale-simple).

Reference : [PyGTK FAQ](http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=show&file=faq08.006.htp)

Comment: If this solution is correct, could you accept the answer please?